# LINQ XML - Select all parent elements where a child has a given value

Tags: xml, vb.net, linq, linq-to-xml

From the XML below,  I need to find information about all flights where  FlightSegmentReference ref equals BA2759,  and then pass some details from the parent elements to a class

```
 If Len(inFlightNo) > 0 Then
     Dim xdoc As XDocument = XDocument.Parse(rawXML)
     Dim results As IEnumerable(Of Offer) =
         From offer In xdoc.Descendants(myns + "FlightSegmentReference")
             Where offer.Attribute("ref") = inFlightNo
                 Select New Offer With
                 {.FlightRef = offer.Attribute("ref")}
     'Return results
 End If
```

This example works fine...  however I need to get more data to  pass to my class,  such as TotalAmount SimpleCurrancyPrice and OfferItemID

```
 If Len(inFlightNo) > 0 Then
     Dim xdoc As XDocument = XDocument.Parse(rawXML)
     Dim results As IEnumerable(Of Offer) =
         From offer In xdoc.Descendants(myns + "FlightSegmentReference")
             Where offer.Attribute("ref") = inFlightNo
                 Select New Offer With
                 {.FlightRef = offer.Attribute("ref"),
                  .Price = ????,
                  .OfferItemID = ????
                 }
     'Return results
 End If
```

What is the best practice method of getting SimpleCurrencyPrice and populating Price in my class

Here is the XML

```
<AirlineOffers>
   <TotalOfferQuantity>1156</TotalOfferQuantity>
   <Owner>BA</Owner>
   <AirlineOffer RequestedDateInd="true">
      <OfferID Owner="BA">OFFER1</OfferID>
      <TotalPrice>
         <SimpleCurrencyPrice Code="GBP">129.50</SimpleCurrencyPrice>
      </TotalPrice>
      <PricedOffer>
         <OfferPrice OfferItemID="1">
            <RequestedDate>
               <PriceDetail>
                  <TotalAmount>
                     <SimpleCurrencyPrice Code="GBP">129.50</SimpleCurrencyPrice>
                  </TotalAmount>
                  <BaseAmount Code="GBP">84.00</BaseAmount>
                  <Taxes>
                     <Total Code="GBP">45.50</Total>
                  </Taxes>
               </PriceDetail>
               <Associations>
                  <AssociatedTraveler>
                     <TravelerReferences>SH1</TravelerReferences>
                  </AssociatedTraveler>
               </Associations>
            </RequestedDate>
         </OfferPrice>
         <Associations>
            <ApplicableFlight>
               <FlightSegmentReference ref="BA2759">
                  <ClassOfService>
                     <Code>O</Code>
                     <MarketingName>Euro Traveller</MarketingName>
                  </ClassOfService>
               </FlightSegmentReference>
            </ApplicableFlight>
            <PriceClass>
               <PriceClassReference>Plus</PriceClassReference>
            </PriceClass>
         </Associations>
         <Associations>
            <ApplicableFlight>
               <FlightSegmentReference ref="BA2764">
                  <ClassOfService>
                     <Code>Q</Code>
                     <MarketingName>Euro Traveller</MarketingName>
                  </ClassOfService>
               </FlightSegmentReference>
            </ApplicableFlight>
            <PriceClass>
               <PriceClassReference>Plus</PriceClassReference>
            </PriceClass>
         </Associations>
      </PricedOffer>
   </AirlineOffer>
   <AirlineOffer RequestedDateInd="true">
      <OfferID Owner="BA">OFFER2</OfferID>
      <TotalPrice>
         <SimpleCurrencyPrice Code="GBP">129.50</SimpleCurrencyPrice>
      </TotalPrice>
      <PricedOffer>
         <OfferPrice OfferItemID="1">
            <RequestedDate>
               <PriceDetail>
                  <TotalAmount>
                     <SimpleCurrencyPrice Code="GBP">129.50</SimpleCurrencyPrice>
                  </TotalAmount>
                  <BaseAmount Code="GBP">84.00</BaseAmount>
                  <Taxes>
                     <Total Code="GBP">45.50</Total>
                  </Taxes>
               </PriceDetail>
               <Associations>
                  <AssociatedTraveler>
                     <TravelerReferences>SH1</TravelerReferences>
                  </AssociatedTraveler>
               </Associations>
            </RequestedDate>
         </OfferPrice>
         <Associations>
            <ApplicableFlight>
               <FlightSegmentReference ref="BA2765">
                  <ClassOfService>
                     <Code>O</Code>
                     <MarketingName>Euro Traveller</MarketingName>
                  </ClassOfService>
               </FlightSegmentReference>
            </ApplicableFlight>
            <PriceClass>
               <PriceClassReference>Plus</PriceClassReference>
            </PriceClass>
         </Associations>
         <Associations>
            <ApplicableFlight>
               <FlightSegmentReference ref="BA2764">
                  <ClassOfService>
                     <Code>Q</Code>
                     <MarketingName>Euro Traveller</MarketingName>
                  </ClassOfService>
               </FlightSegmentReference>
            </ApplicableFlight>
            <PriceClass>
               <PriceClassReference>Plus</PriceClassReference>
            </PriceClass>
         </Associations>
      </PricedOffer>
   </AirlineOffer>
</AirlineOffers>
```

Comment: How is the price and OfferID related to the selected flight segment?  Price code seems to be in the same <Association> elelment, but I'm not seeing how OfferId is related at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not a VB developer but I think is easy what I going to propose, instead of select `FlightSegmentReference` nodes, select `PricedOffer` which is the element that have all the info you need, so it would be:

```
Dim results As IEnumerable(Of Offer) =
      From offer In xdoc.Descendants(myns + "PricedOffer")
      Where offer.Descendants(myns +"FlightSegmentReference")
                  .Any(Function(e) e.Attribute("ref").Value = inFlightNo)
      Select New Offer() With {
                          .FlightRef = inFlightNo,
                          .Price = offer.Descendants(myns +"SimpleCurrencyPrice").FirstOrDefault().Value
                          .OfferItemID =offer.Element(myns +"OfferPrice").Attribute("OfferItemID").Value 
}
```

Comment: This does seem like the better way to go.

Comment: Thanks so much,  not only does it work,  but I understand it too.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Parent` to navigate back up the tree from the FlightSegmentReference element:

```vb
Dim results As IEnumerable(Of Offer) =
    From ref In xdoc.Descendants(myns + "FlightSegmentReference")
    Where ref.Attribute("ref") = inFlightNo
    Let offer = ref.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent
    Select New Offer With {
        .FlightRef = ref.Attribute("ref"),
        .Price = CDec(offer.Element(myns + "TotalPrice").Element(myns + "SimpleCurrencyPrice").Value),
        .OfferItemID = offer.Element(myns + "PricedOffer").Element(myns + "OfferPrice").Attribute("OfferItemID")
    }
```

I like using VB.NET's XML syntax support - it seems more readable to me, although you will need to [`Import`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/imports-statement-xml-namespace) your namespace:

```vb
Dim results2 As IEnumerable(Of Offer) =
    From e In xdoc...<myns:FlightSegmentReference>
    Where e.@ref = inFlightNo
    Let offer = e.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent
    Select New Offer() With {
        .FlightRef = e.@ref,
        .Price = CDec(offer.<myns:TotalPrice>.<myns:SimpleCurrencyPrice>.Value),
        .OfferItemID = offer.<myns:PricedOffer>.<myns:OfferPrice>.@OfferItemID
    }
```